# WPF multithreading. Changing the interface of a third-party flow

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

WPF C #. I have a method that binds to a different method.
The server sends a hello world.

```
 var clientobj =
 (OperClass) Activator.GetObject
 (
 typeof (OperClass),
 "tcp :/ / localhost: 100001/TcpClient"
 );

clientobj.Update ("HELLO WORLD");
```

client application:

```
public void Update (string msg)
{
     label1.text = msg; / / error thread
}
```

The programs are used for communication RemotingServices.Marshal.
How can I change the text to label1. **dispatcher** does not help.

Comment: What is the error you get? Is it a cross-thread error when trying to set `label1.Text`?

Comment: Yes you are correct this error. Can not get the flow of control, because the item was not created in its thread.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access UI elements from a thread that is not the thread the UI elements were created on. To overcome this, you will need to invoke what you need on the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615907.aspx) thread that the UI elements were created on.

Assuming `clientobj` is a UI element in itself (such as a `Window` or `UserControl`), then you can using the following code:

```
public void Update (string msg)
{
    // See if we need to re-invoke on the Dispatcher thread
    if (!CheckAccess())
    {
        // Invoke on the Dispatcher thread
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<string>(Update), msg);

        // Exit from this method to prevent continued execution
        return;
    }

    // We are now running on the Dispatcher thread, so we can access the UI element(s) directly
    label1.Text = msg;
}
```

Comment: The program worked. First came the method included in the condition. Then re-call a method to rename the UI. But the program did not change. Maybe you need to call update?

Comment: @Feor I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: Your code worked. But in the interface changes do not. Although there was no error. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Strangely when debug was producing, then the values ​​are changing. I concluded to check on the BUTTON values. And when you press, nothing has changed, everything was as before.

Comment: Do you mean the value of `label1.Text` *has* changed when stepping through with the debugger, but the UI doesn't display the change?

Comment: That is interesting. Is the value still different if you enter into the method for a second time?

Comment: Calling twice. The values ​​that I used for the first time are the same. Ie the message hello world in the second call is the same.

Comment: I was the second day of sitting with this problem. Can you help me source code? I am very grateful that you are trying to help me.

Comment: Sure, if you post your source code onto PasteBin (a simplified version if it's complex) then I shall take a look at it.

Comment: Here's the source files. If you need something to add tell me.
http://pastebin.com/u/Jinfaa

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7421/discussion-between-samuel-slade-and-feor)